# 'list' object has no attribute 'shape

Tags: python-3.x, keras, nlp, word-embedding, bert-language-model

I am passing an embedding matrix to the embedding layer in Keras

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_words, 30, input_length=max_len, weights=[all]))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.5))
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.8))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()
```

Here `all` in the embedding layer is my embedding matrix. When I pass this, it gives the following error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-6e84a6e5254a> in <module>()
      1 model = Sequential()
----> 2 model.add(Embedding(max_words, 30, input_length=max_len, weights=[all]))
      3 model.add(BatchNormalization())
      4 model.add(Activation('tanh'))
      5 model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.5))

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in set_weights(self, weights)
   1120         param_values = K.batch_get_value(params)
   1121         for pv, p, w in zip(param_values, params, weights):
-> 1122             if pv.shape != w.shape:
   1123                 raise ValueError('Layer weight shape ' +
   1124                                  str(pv.shape) +

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Comment: it seems that all is a list, you must pass a numpy array

Comment: should I do embeddings = np.array(all) and then pass weights = [embeddings]

Comment: you can try, remember that the embeddings matrix must have this dimension (num_token+1, emb_dim) where '+1' means the padding token embedding (if present)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case, `embeddings` matrix was inside a list that caused the problem.

Changing

```
embeddings = embd.create_embedding_matrix_cnn(train_word_index, w2v_model, EMBEDDING_DIM)
```

to this

```
vocab_size, embeddings = embd.create_embedding_matrix_cnn(train_word_index, w2v_model, EMBEDDING_DIM)
```

Solved the problem.